# Display HTML in an Actionscript 3 project

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, xhtml

Folks,

I am pulling all my Flash (pure AS3 project, not Flash CS3) content from a Drupal back-end for SEO purposes.  This works great, except the HTML rendering built into the TextField object leaves a lot to be desired.  Could anyone recommend any libraries that would allow me to display HTML elements?  At this stage, commercial or open-source libraries are welcome.

Thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 4):

you might also want to try:
http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/

I haven't used it but it looks like it does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

AIR introduces a `DisplayObject` called `flash.html.HTMLLoader`. It's powered by WebKit, so if your content is compatible with Safari, it will work with `HTMLLoader`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Flex HTML component](http://drumbeatinsight.com/htmlcomponent) available that's pretty good. It uses the browser to render the contents.

However it's not free. You will have to invest $149.

You can test the capabilities of this component [here](http://drumbeatinsight.com/examples/htmlcomponent/iframe/HTMLFrameInApplication.html).

Answer (score 1):

2Synthmax http://as3htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Flex iFrame, which is modeled after it's HTML iframe counterpart.  I haven't used this solution in my Flex applications yet, but it looks promising.

http://deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm

However, please note that this same author now recommends **against** using this.

As always, your mileage may vary,
Randy Stegbauer

Answer (score 0):

Does your swf need to fill all of the web page?  Why not have your swf call some javascript that will populate a DIV or whatever. Or just have the PHP generate that. I guess I need more information what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

So long as your project is viewed within a web browser, your best bet would be to overlay HTML content in a DIV or iFrame above the Flash content using a JavaScript tool such as [JQery's ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try out this [AS3 HTML Parser Library](http://as3htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) ... works well for my needs, It currently supports most elements (including img, span, div).