# Simple RichTextEditor Alternative for flex?

Tags: apache-flex, text, editor, wysiwyg

Does anyone know a good alternative to the RichTextEditor component in flex?
It only needs to be able to set `<li>`'s and `<strong>`'s

Comment: check these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466061/recommendations-for-an-html-friendly-richtexteditor-for-flex-air

Answer (score 0):

you can use **TextArea** and it **htmlText** property

[Using the htmlText property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d52.html)

hopes that helps

Answer (score 0):

`<li>`'s are supported, but not `<strong>`, use `<b>` instead.  If you can't control it, just replace them.

I would try to use TLF components if possible like RichText and RichEditableText. If you need an editor, you might want to look at [Elad's implementation](http://elromdesign.com/blog/2011/01/28/flex-4-tlf-rich-text-editor/).